# Interrupt calling thread when exception in child task

Tags: c#, exception, task, task-parallel-library

I have the following scenario:

I have a plugin class (unfortunately synchronous and that's out of my control) which runs automation scripts. At startup, a task is started which runs in the background continuously until the user stops it. As this task runs, it is parsing streaming incoming data from a serial port and continuously updating a list of responses. In parallel, the script will be changing some other values and monitoring how the responses react.

My problem is this -- it is possible that the parser could throw an exception and that renders any of the remaining script invalid. But, I can't find a good way to interrupt the script (i.e. void Main() below) should this parallel task throw. If I wait until my script is done, and then await the task, I do get the exception, but by then there is potentially a lot of time wasted. So I'm looking for better ways to interrupt the script that is running should the parallel task error. I've tried posting on the initial synchronization context but with no luck as well. I've parred down an example below to simulate a similar scenario

```
public class Test : TestPlugin
{
    Task _t;
    List<string> data = new List();

    public Test(){ }
    
    public override void Cleanup()
    {
        //_t.Wait();
    }
    
    public override void Main()
    {
        // i want this to be interrupted if the polling task started in startup throws. 
        //Right here simulates running test steps, 
        //any of which can access the data that's been updated by the "background" task at any time
        try
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < 10)
            {
                Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("step" + i + "Latest: " + data.latest());
                i++;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION");
        }
    }

    public override void Setup()
    {
        _t = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            int i =0;
            while (i < 10)
            {
                await Task.Delay(200);
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                i++;
                //i would parse incoming data and add to array here
                data.add(i);
                if (i > 3) throw new Exception("UH OH");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to terminate the subtask while the exception happened in main task? something like that?

Comment: The opposite, i want to terminate main if the subtask '_t' throws. If my parser bombs out there is something wrong with the incoming data, rendering the results from the Main() method invalid.

Comment: The simplest way to change your code to do what you want is for the main loop to check [Task.IsFaulted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.isfaulted?view=net-5.0) with each iteration. However, it is probably a bad idea for the subtask to allow an exception to bubble all the way out of the task. Instead, you should consider passing in a [CancellationTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=net-5.0) to allow the subtask to signal the main loop from a `catch` block when it errs.

Comment: @gfree a task isn't a thread. It's a *promise* that something will complete in the *future*. It may or may not execute on a theadpool thread. IO for example doesn't use threads. The easiest way to do what you want is to use `await`.  This will await for the asynchronous operation and either return the result or rethrow any exception

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am aware a task isn't a thread. I suppose that maybe in my scenario a task is the wrong solution. I cannot await the task because I need to call Task.Run(); Then I need to change other values *in parallel* while the task is running, all within the Main method. So I expect the task to start and then the next line(s) of code in Main to execute immediately while the task is running in the background.

Comment: Of course you can- `await Task.Run(()=>whatever);` Although you don't need to. The code you posted only contains asynchronous operations, so you could put it into an `async Task` method  directly,eg `async Task Main()`. If you want your main thread to do something else in parallel, just store the task returned by `Task.Run` or the asynchronous method to a field or variable and `await` it when you want to get its results. `await` doesn't block anyway. You could start many tasks and await all of them.

Comment: Instead of `Task.Delay(1000).Wait();` you should use `await Task.Delay();`. Once you do that, you no longer need `Task.Run`

Comment: In `Main` you could do `Task.WaitAny(Task.Delay(1000), _t);`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos " If you want your main thread to do something else in parallel, just store the task returned by Task.Run or the asynchronous method to a field or variable and await it when you want to get its results." That's exactly what I'm doing in the above example.  The problem is the task is updating a list (see example above). Assume it throws an exception when an item fails to be added for some reason. I will *never* know that it happened until I await the task. That could be 20 minutes later when the test is finished. I think wrapping my subsequent code in a task and using WaitAny

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos may be the correct solution. as charlieface mentions above

Comment: Only problem is you get `AggregateExceptions` which you need to unwrap. If you can't make it `async Task` then best to declare `async void`, and call `await Task.WhenAny` which will unwrap for you

Answer (score 0):

You could investigate the `Task.ContinueWith` method on the calling task code.
this `ContinueWith` allows for a delegate callback that gets triggered on completion and/or exceptions. so perhaps within the `ContinueWith` delegate, do a check if the task completes successfully, if not then raise a new exception there appending the thrown exception passed to the delegate.

You can use the code below as an example:

```
Task t1 = factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    DoSomething();
}).ContinueWith((t2) =>
{
    if (t2.IsCanceled)
        DoSomethingWhenCancelled();
    else if (t2.IsFaulted)
        DoSomethingOnError(t1.Exception);
    else
        DoSomethingWhenComplete();
});
```

Comment: Or use `await`. `await Task.Run(()=>DoSomething());` will rethrow any exceptions

Comment: Good answer, but you can make this even better by using the `ContinueWith` overload that uses [`TaskContinuationOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions?view=net-5.0), which can specify exactly when that continuation is run (for example, only on success or error).

Comment: I tried this but if I rethrow the exception here it isn't going to interrupt the main method from executing.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am going to have to end up with something like the following. Unfortunately this forces developers of these test procedures to need to wrap all test steps that execute in parallel to the serial port reader with a task, but maybe it's possible for me to abstract away that implementation detail into a class with an API that manages this a bit better for them.

```
public override void Main()
{
    Task steps = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        int i = 1;
        //this represents step 1
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        i++;
        Console.WriteLine("Step " + i);

        //this represents step 2
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        i++;
        Console.WriteLine("Step " + i);

        //this represents step 3
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        i++;
        Console.WriteLine("Step " + i);

        //this represents step 4
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        i++;
        Console.WriteLine("Step " + i);
    });

    Task.WaitAny(_t, steps);
}
```